Webhook which sends the payload to google App script and sheet based on document addition in Panda
Greetings!
I am building one app script to fetch the payload from Panda and put it to Google Sheet.
So the scenario is:
Document created/updated in pandoc > Webhook triggered and it will send data to Google Sheet based on logic in App script.
I have created a webapp and dopost function to fetch the payload but i dont know how to run it because manually running gives an error as dopost function is not defined.
This is script I am trying to run:
function doPost(e) {
  // Check if postData is present
  if (!e.postData || !e.postData.contents) {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('No payload received.');
  }
  
  const payload = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
  
  // Log the payload
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2));
  
  // Add the payload to the sheet
  appendPayloadToSheet(payload);

  // Return the payload as text output
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}

/**
 * Append the payload data to the Google Sheet
 */
function appendPayloadToSheet(payload) {
  const spreadsheetId = ''; // Replace with your Google Sheets ID
  const sheetName = ''; // Replace with your sheet name
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Extract data from payload
  const event = payload.event;
  const data = payload.data;
  const id = data.id;
  const name = data.name;
  const dateCreated = data.date_created;
  const dateModified = data.date_modified;
  const status = data.status;
  const recipientEmail = data.recipients[0].email;
  
  // Append the data to the sheet
  sheet.appendRow([event, id, name, dateCreated, dateModified, status, recipientEmail]);
}

I have tried to deploy it and run it but the manually running gives an error as "event not defined".

deploy the Web App and trigger it by an HTTP POST request

Hi , I have deployed it but how to trigger it because I am confused over there. is it like i have to add HTTP post request in script? but as the webhook is sending payload to webapp why would we need HTTP request in script then?

after deploying, you will get a URL that looks something like https://script.google.com/macros/s/your-script-id/exec. this is the URL you need to provide to Panda for the webhook

That is also done, But can you tell if the script I have written is correct or not. I am not sure if it is correct or not.

looks correct to me. you could add some error handlings tho (posted as answer)

try:
 // Handle GET requests
 
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('GET requests are not supported. Please use POST.');
}


 // Handle POST requests
 
function doPost(e) {
  try {
    // Check if postData is present
    if (!e.postData || !e.postData.contents) {
      return ContentService.createTextOutput('No payload received.');
    }

    // Parse the incoming payload
    const payload = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

    // Log the payload for debugging purposes
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2));

    // Append the payload data to the Google Sheet
    appendPayloadToSheet(payload);

    // Return the payload as JSON response
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(payload, null, 2)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error in doPost: ' + error.message);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput('Error: ' + error.message);
  }
}


 // Append the payload data to the Google Sheet
 
function appendPayloadToSheet(payload) {
  try {
    const spreadsheetId = 'your-spreadsheet-id'; // Replace with your Google Sheets ID
    const sheetName = 'your-sheet-name'; // Replace with your sheet name
    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);

    if (!sheet) {
      throw new Error('Sheet not found: ' + sheetName);
    }

    // Extract data from the payload
    const event = payload.event || 'N/A';
    const data = payload.data || {};
    const id = data.id || 'N/A';
    const name = data.name || 'N/A';
    const dateCreated = data.date_created || 'N/A';
    const dateModified = data.date_modified || 'N/A';
    const status = data.status || 'N/A';
    const recipientEmail = (data.recipients && data.recipients[0]) ? data.recipients[0].email : 'N/A';

    // Append the data to the sheet
    sheet.appendRow([event, id, name, dateCreated, dateModified, status, recipientEmail]);
  } catch (error) {
    Logger.log('Error in appendPayloadToSheet: ' + error.message);
  }
}



Save script in Google Apps Script.

Deploy as Web App:

Click on Deploy -> New Deployment
Under Select type, choose Web app
Set Description (optional)
Under Execute as, select Me
Under Who has access, select Anyone, even anonymous
Click Deploy


Authorize the Script: Follow the prompts to authorize the script to access your Google Sheets

Trigger the Webhook: Use a tool like Postman or a simple HTTP request to trigger the webhook and send a test payload to the deployed web app URL

Check Logs: Use Logger.log statements to debug and view logs in the Apps Script Dashboard under Executions




Got this error when accessing payload:Script function not found: doGet

The main issue is payload is not getting reached from Pandadoc to App script.

@DhruvinSheth error you're seeing, "Script function not found: doGet," indicates that the script is being triggered by a GET request rather than a POST request. code updated
